# Drop spark dataframe from cache

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using Spark 1.3.0 with python api. While transforming huge dataframes, I cache many DFs for faster execution;

```
df1.cache()
df2.cache()
```

Once use of certain dataframe is over and is no longer needed how can I drop DF from memory (or un-cache it??)?

For example, `df1` is used through out the code while `df2` is utilized for few transformations and after that, it is never needed.  I want to forcefully drop `df2` to release more memory space.

Comment: @Paul For the record, the reason this is actually not a duplicate is because the DataFrame API is different from the RDD API.  This method call in particular is shared between them, however.

Answer (score 84):

just do the following:

```
df1.unpersist()
df2.unpersist()
```

> Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out
>   old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you
>   would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall
>   out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method.

Comment: And pay attention to unpersist the df after the end of the lineage, so after the last action that involves the cached df.

Comment: I tried this for one of my dataframes "df" and when I did df.show(), df was still displaying data. When does it actually unpersist?

Comment: @spacedustpi it  removes the dataframe from the cache. (Somewhere in memory or on disk if not enough space in memory) By calling show, you triggered an action and then the computation has been done from the beginning to show you the data.

Answer (score 42):

If the dataframe **registered as a table for SQL operations**, like

```
df.createGlobalTempView(tableName) // or some other way as per spark verision
```

then the cache can be dropped with following commands, *off-course spark also does it automatically*

## Spark >= 2.x

Here `spark` is an object of `SparkSession`

> - Drop a specific table/df from cache
>
>   ```
>    spark.catalog.uncacheTable(tableName)
>   ```
> - Drop all tables/dfs from cache
>
>   ```
>    spark.catalog.clearCache()
>   ```

---

## Spark <= 1.6.x

> - Drop a specific table/df from cache
>
>   ```
>    sqlContext.uncacheTable(tableName)
>   ```
> - Drop all tables/dfs from cache
>
>   ```
>    sqlContext.clearCache()
>   ```

Comment: I tried these for my RDD 'df'. Why does type df.show() still display data?

Comment: df.show()  will display data irrespective of cache, as long as the input source for the data frame is available.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need to block during removal => df2.unpersist(true)
2. Unblocking removal => df2.unpersist()

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple utility context manager that takes care of that for you:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def cached(df):
    df_cached = df.cache()
    try:
        yield df_cached
    finally:
        df_cached.unpersist()
```

Comment: would probably be helpful for some if you mention usage as `with cached(df) as df_cached: `