# When and how to explicitly unpersist intermediate dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, persist

In our Pyspark applications, we run iterative algorithms on very large dataframes (many billions data points) and need to persist() a lot. Automatic memory clean-up doesn't seem to work for us (wrong data gets purged first), and so we are trying to manually unpersist() certain intermediate dataframes. I would appreciate answers to the following two questions:

1. How do we know at what point a particular intermediate dataframe can be unpersisted? For instance, let's say, there is one previously persisted dataframe df1 and I obtain another dataframe df2 from it (or from it and something else via join()). Will it be safe to unpersist df1 after calling df2.persist()? If not (which I suspect is the case), can methods toDF() or createDataFrame() be used to create such decoupling?
2. Sometimes, we would like to release memory of all *but* few previously persisted dataframes. Our guessed solution is to call

   ```
   spark.catalog.clearCache()
   ```

   and immediately follow it by new persist() on the dataframes we'd like to keep in memory, but this is just a guess, and I don't have any solid justification for this.

So, what is the *right* way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218769/drop-spark-dataframe-from-cache