# Clear cache of the specified table in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching, pyspark

I'm wondering how to eliminate cache of the specified spark dataframe.

For example,

```
sdf = spark.read.table('example)
sdf.count() # -> And the sdf will be cached in memory
```

After the `sdf.count()` sdf is stored in memory. I'd like to remove it from memory to make room.

I know two possible candidates, which don't work to solve the question above.

- `spark.catalog.clearCache()` method: this clears all the in-memory cache of the tables.
- `sdf.unpersist()` :  This only works after such codes as  `sdf.repartition(200).persist()` and `sdf.count().`

In addition, I've got to use Spark v2.4.0 due to some constraints of my working environment.

Would anyone please tell me how to achieve above?

Comment: is it helpful? .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218769/drop-spark-dataframe-from-cache